# Passportjs with Typescript

Tags: typescript, passport.js

I'm trying to use passport in a typescript project. In all of the example the `done` callback function is called with the `null` value. But I get the typescript error `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Error | undefined'`. I can make it work using `done(null as any, profile);`. The problem is probably with `@type/passport`. I googled this this problem, but didn't find anything, so I'm guessing that I did something wrong (I don't think I'm the only person using typescript with passport).

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
  callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL
}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  return done(null, profile);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The common format of callback functions is `callback(error: Error | string | undefined, successData: SpecifiedType)` which means when you encounter an error condition, the first parameter could be passed as an `Error` object or just plain string describing the reason of the error. If there is no error you can pass `undefined`. Since it is common to check `if(error)` in the callback function implementation, any falsy value such as `null` would do the job.

Since you are using Typescript, it is recommending you the way the library author intended to receive the falsy value for the error parameter in the callback, and it is `undefined`. So, in your case, you may `return done(undefined, profile);` without any issue.

---

Just to ensure that `undefined` is fine when there is no error, I had a look at the Google Strategy test case here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/blob/2399ef47f00b47ac587f056f2f100a2c4db81928/test/strategy.profile.test.js#L73-L79

```js
      strategy.userProfile('token', function(err, p) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        profile = p;
        done();
      });
```

You see, `done` is passing nothing, which is same as passing `undefined`. If you dig into source, I bet you could find where error is handled. But, it does not matter as long as error is falsy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But even the passport docs for example http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/ uses`null` everywhere and not `undefined`. Every other example in the internet uses null too. There is a difference between `null` and `undefined`, I know it's probably gonna work without any issue but still, the question that why I can't use `null` like everyone else that uses javascript instead of typescript is not answered in your response.

Comment: It happens with other callback functions too. I think there is a chance that somewhere `if (err === null)` will be used, or changed to it, so if I update my passport version my code will break. I think there's a possibility that this will cause issues in the future. From http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/: `...Ensure that err remains null, and use the final argument to pass additional details.` My opinion is that `null` should be used, it's just cleaner and more consistent with available examples.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question Using `null as any` is ugly but I think it's the best and better then using `undefined` or an empty string which should also work because its `falsy`.

Comment: hmm, then you are not obeying what Typescript is suggesting. I think this makes an excellent case raise a ticket here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/passport and probably tag the creators as mentioned on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/passport

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right place. I will rise an issue there and see how it goes. If it's a problem on their part I will accept your answer.